# Google AppEngine Search API only returns 20 results, even though there are more

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-search-api

When I search the AppEngine Search API, it is only returning 20 results, even though I have 68 items in the index. The reference documentation says it can return up to 10,000 results. How do I return more results?

#### Code

```
public Results<ScoredDocument> search(String q) {
    log.severe("Searching with query: " + q);
    try {
        Results<ScoredDocument> results = getIndex().search(q);
        log.severe("results.size:"+results.getNumberReturned());

public Index getIndex() {
    IndexSpec indexSpec = IndexSpec.newBuilder().setName("OnixIndex").build(); 
    Index index = SearchServiceFactory.getSearchService().getIndex(indexSpec);
    return index;
}
```

#### Log

```
E 2013-12-03 17:55:49.858
com.mwv.pic.service.SearchService search: Searching with query: 
E 2013-12-03 17:55:51.446
com.mwv.pic.service.SearchService search: results.size:20
```

#### Index

[image: Imgur]

#### Version

appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.8.6.jar

#### Reference

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the number of items in the results has some default pagination. The number you're looking for is `getNumberFound()` which should contain the expected number of results satisfying the query.

Comment: Thanks. Also found https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/options. Has the solution.